# UWP NavigationView как изменить ширину бокового меню

Tags: uwp

Я хочу изменить ширину меню навигации, чтобы оно адаптировалось к имеющемуся в нем контексту, то есть к кнопкам. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <NavigationView
        x:Name="NavigationView"
        Margin="0,30,0,0"
        x:FieldModifier="private"
        AlwaysShowHeader="False"
        CompactModeThresholdWidth="8"
        ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="8"
        IsSettingsVisible="False"
        SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged">
    
    ...Buttons
    
        </Grid>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]